# IOS: How can ios app in sleep mode/ background recieve data from server and send peripheral device?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

Im try creating a IoT device and ios app.
But i wondering that my idea is possible or not. If its possible, please tell me solution.

[image]

⚫︎What I want create⚫︎
・Two IoT devices can communicate remotely with sending signal.
・Device is connecting ios App with bluetooth(BLE)
・when you press button of device, device post signal to server via ios app.
・and another device can recieve signal from server via ios App.

⚫︎Problem⚫︎
・I can recieve data from firestore when ios is sleep mode / background
・I can post data to firestore when ios is sleep mode / background

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    }

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import Firebase


class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    // BLE
    private let deviceName:String = "********"
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var peripheral: CBPeripheral!
    private var characteristic: CBCharacteristic!

    var value: CUnsignedChar = 0
    var discoverPeripherals: [CBPeripheral] = []

    var discoverPeripheralNames: [String] = []


    enum ConnState {
        case off
        case scan
        case connect
        case disconnect
    }
    var cstate: ConnState = .off
    var signalState: Int = 0

    private let targetService: CBUUID = CBUUID(string: "FF10")
    private let targetCharacteristic: CBUUID = CBUUID(string: "FF11")

    // Firestore
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var listener: ListenerRegistration?


    // --------------------------------
    // 1
    // --------------------------------
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // 1-1
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        scanStartBtn.isEnabled = false
        switchBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.listenDocument()
      }

    // -------------------------------
    // In Here, when ios recieve data, I want to write signal to BLE Device
    // ------------------------------- 
    private func listenDocument() {
        // [START listen_document]
        db.collection("users").document("*****")
            .addSnapshotListener { [self] documentSnapshot, error in
                guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                    print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
            guard let data = document.data() else {
                print("Document data was empty.")
                return
            }
            
            if cstate == .connect {
                print("connected！ \(data)")
                if signalState == 0 {
                    value = 1
                    peripheral.writeValue(Data(bytes: &value, count: 1), for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
                    signalState = 1
                } else {
                    value = 0
                    peripheral.writeValue(Data(bytes: &value, count: 1), for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
                    signalState = 0
                }
            }
        }
    // [END listen_document]
    }

    // --------------------------------
    // 2
    // --------------------------------
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            scanStartBtn.isEnabled = true
            print("Bluetooth poweredOn")
        } else {
            print("Bluetooth poweredOFF")
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------
    // 3
    // --------------------------------
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    
    if peripheral.name == "*******" {
        self.peripheral = peripheral

        // stop scan
        print("stop scan")
        centralManager.stopScan()

        // starting to connect Peripheral
        print("connect...")
        scanStartBtn.setTitle("Connecting", for: .normal)
        centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------
    // 3
    // --------------------------------
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("connected")
        scanStartBtn.setTitle("Connect", for: .normal)
        peripheral.delegate = self

        // 4
        peripheral.discoverServices([targetService])
    }

    // --------------------------------
    // 3-3
    // --------------------------------
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("connect failed")
    }

    // --------------------------------
    // 4-2
    // --------------------------------
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("discover service error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        for service in peripheral.services! {
            // 5-1
            print("discover characteristic FF11")
            scanStartBtn.setTitle("Searching Charactor", for: .normal)
             peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([targetCharacteristic], for: service)
        }
    }


    // --------------------------------
    // 5-2
    // --------------------------------
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral,    didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("discover chara error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        print("discovered characteristic FF11")
        for charact in service.characteristics! {
            scanStartBtn.setTitle("Dissconnect", for: .normal)
            cstate = .connect
            switchBtn.isEnabled = true
            self.characteristic = charact
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------
    // 6-2:
    // --------------------------------
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("discconected")
        cstate = .off
        switchBtn.isEnabled = false
        scanStartBtn.setTitle("Connect", for: .normal)
    }

    func turnOn() {
        print("write on")
    }
}
```

⚫︎Done⚫︎
・connect raspbery pi to original IOS app through bluetooth(BLE)
・device could recieve push notification from google/firestore when ios app in active.

Im new to swift and IoT, and I did tons of google search includes apple documents, but I couldn't do this....
Now, Im straggle with ios LifeCycle..
Is there any way? if so, how can I make it? Please Help me..
Thank you for answering!!

Comment: You can't expect someone to write the whole program for you... Post a minimal required code that does what you want in foreground mode, but fails in background mode, and then someone can take a look at the specific issue with the background mode.

Comment: “I can [receive] data from firestore when ios is sleep mode / background” … we would generally reach for push notifications when we want second device to be notified of the event.

Comment: @KirilS.

Thank you advicing ! Yes, Sorry, You are right.To ask here is almost new for me..
But I put code!

Comment: @Rob
Thanks for answer!
I have no idea to use "push notifications".
I will try to use it!

Comment: I found to use Apple Push Notification Service.
I will try this way.

Comment: Did using Apple Push Notification Service helped you? if it is, could you please post it as an answer to help the community? Thanks.